# Unable to set .css() method on condition check

Tags: javascript, html, css

***functionality:***

The first row of data in the table should be in font color white, while the rest of the data in the table should be in font color orange.

***Issue:***

At this point, the entire row of data is in orange, it is unable to set the first row of the data to be in orange while the rest of the data to be in white. What is the issue? please help.

```js
var data = "A,4.0,00:04@B,5.0,00:05@C,9.0,00:09";
var playerList = data.split("@");

var innerList;
for (i = 0; i < playerList.length; i++) {
  var [name, , score] = playerList[i].split(",");
  var [minute, second] = score.split(":");

  $("#Player_Name")
    .html(function(index, html) {
      var prop = index === 0 ? name : score;
      return html + prop + "<br>"
    })

  $("#Player_Minute_Score, #Player_Second_Score").html(function(index, html) {

    var prop = index == 0 ? minute : second;

    return html + prop + "<p>"
  })
}
```

```css
#Rugby_Scoreboard {
  position: absolute;
  left: 335px;
  top: 182px;
  width: 825px;
  height: 818px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#Rugby_Scoreboard div {
  z-index: 50;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
  width: 1080px;
  color: #ff8c04;
}

#Rugby_Scoreboard div font {
  display: block;
}

#Rugby_Scoreboard div font:first-child {
  color: white;
}

#Player_Name {
  left: 120px;
}

#Player_Minute_Score {
  left: 580px;
}

#Player_Second_Score {
  left: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Game_LeaderBoard" style="position:absolute; z-index:6; top:0px; left:0px; width: 1920px; heigth: 1000px; margin:auto;">

  <table id="Rugby_Scoreboard">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="Player_Name">
          <font face="OpenSans-Bold"></font>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div id="Player_Minute_Score">
          <font face="OpenSans-Bold"></font>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td>
        <div id="Player_Second_Score">
          <font face="OpenSans-Bold"></font>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: `var [name, , score]` it has two commas. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Jai no, it is delibrate, as i am not intending to assign any array variable to the the middle data of the array

Comment: Can you please include enough code to reproduce the issue? You have undefined variables (data) here and I'm guessing you're also using jQuery, but can't be sure.

Comment: @Luke Your question is still giving a syntax error when it is run; unless this error is fixed and we get a working demo that reproduces your issue, we won't be able to help you very much.

Comment: @Luke So, now the code is working, but it's being written to the console, where CSS formatting doesn't apply. Can you make it write the code in the HTML where it will be displayed?

Comment: @TylerH is this it?? I have removed the console.log

Comment: @Luke Yep. So now the issue is you are inserting all your names into a single element. You need to create a new div for each name and then paste those divs into the HTML with your jQuery code. Then you can target it with `div font div:first-child { color: white }`

Comment: @TylerH So that means if i have 10 names....I will need 10 different div?

Comment: @Luke if you want to target it with CSS, yes. You could do some complex parsing of the text with JavaScript but that would be inefficient. Ideally you would use a table structure for this, and store everything in `<td>` and `<tr>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing # in `#Player_Second_Score` the id selector is missing when you call the .html jquery function so you are not getting index and it is never == 0 so the function .css is not being called

But why are you even using jquery ? You can use the css pseudo-element `:first-child` or `:nth-child(odd, even, or child number)`

This has some other typos that need to be fixed, like second in `[minute, seconod]` no worries happens to all of us

Comment: I don't really understand the part where you are using css pseudo-element. Anyway, I have done the typo but still unable to get the desired css

Comment: @TylerH You didn't add in anything

Comment: @Luke Sorry, hit enter too soon: https://jsfiddle.net/spvu8uog/2/ Specifically line 19 in the CSS section

Comment: @TylerH I have kind of have followed exactly to the jfiddle provided, but it doesn't seem to have worked. i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Add ); atthe end after } that will brick your whole code. And the way nth child works is like this `tr:nth-child(1)>td{ color: #ffffff; }` you can also use first-child what this does is make the text color of all the td white in the first tr

For some reason it wasnt allowing me to reply to the comment

Comment: Wouldn't this make other <tr> tag in other table tag to follow the same property as well?

Comment: Yes but u can give the table that u want to edit a classand edit the tr of that class